# bash script for seismic date

Tags: bash, pdf

I have the following command and the original work 100 %,

- the original

```
suchw key1=gstat key3=gelev c=-1 b=-0.00245187 key2=gy a=11803.7 d=3.2 < cmp.su > cmp_geophon_statik.su &
#suchw key1=sstat key3=selev c=-1 b=-0.00245187 key2=sy a=11803.7 d=3.2 < cmp_geophon_statik.su > cmp_statik.su &
#sustatic hdrs=1 sign=1 < cmp_statik.su > cmp_mit_statik.su &
#cat cmp_mit_statik.su | suwind key=ep min=1195 max=1197 | supsimage perc=95 title='der siemogram nach staitch' > evince www.pdf &
```

not: with last commend I tried to export the result to pdf file but it look like not work exactly just i would

but i wanted to write it like bash script(like 'trt.su') and i wrot them so,

```
#!/bin/bash
cat cmp.su \
| suchw key1=gstat key3=gelev c=-1 b=-0.00211187t key2=gy a=11803.7 d=3.2 \
| > cmp_geophon_statik.su &&
exit

#cat cmp_geophon_statik.su \
#| suchw key1=sstat key3=selev c=-1 b=$geschwindigkeit key2=sy a=11803.7 d=3.2 \
#| >> cmp_statik.su
#exit

#cat cmp_statik.su \
#| sustatic hdrs=1 sign=1 \
#| >> cmp_mit_statik.su 
#exit
cat cmp_mit_statik.su | suwind key=ep min=913 max=913 | suxwigb clip=10
```

but they didn't worked.
can you help me?

Comment: Remove the last pipe. `command | > file` should be `command > file`. Why do you even want pipes? Your first command is shorter and runs more efficiently.

Comment: really I am junior in bash, thanx